# Is there a word to describe what someone is worth, economically?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that describes what someone is worth, economically?

For example, if Joe has gone to school for five years and has a bachelor's degree in Computer Science, there is a certain minimum value on him. He can easily make more than $15/hour, so that would mean that he is minimally worth $15/hour.

Comment: Is the word "cost" unsuitable?

Comment: I was thinking more of "self minimum wage", but when you say "cost", wouldn't that be from the perspective of an employer?

Comment: It's Joe's floccinaucinihilipilification value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "net worth" in economics means a person's total balance of assets, although you're probably looking for something more akin to a person's "market price".

I suppose you could use "base wage" or "worth of labour" to describe what you're talking about.

Comment: "Base wage" sounds good. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the term *[market rate](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/market-rate.html)*.  This applies to a wide variety of valuable things, not just people.